# Xen API Ruby Bindings?

Tags: xen, ruby

Does anyone know if there is a full implementation of the Xen API in ruby floating around out there somewhere?  I found this:  http://github.com/rubiojr/pangea/tree/master  but it is read only and is not fully developed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about xen directly, but there are ruby bindings for libvirt, which can handle many kinds of vms, including xen.

http://libvirt.org/ruby/